# Hyperledger -- how to set up REST API for invoking Chaincode

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I'm playing around with Hyperledger and am trying to figure to figure how to set up the server with REST api for chaincode defined here https://openblockchain.readthedocs.io/en/latest/API/CoreAPI/#rest-api

Unfortunately many of the links are dead, so I'm not sure how to set it up. I understand the query language, I just don't knopw how to begin the web server.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Hyperledger Fabric v1.0 and later does not provide a native REST API for interacting with peer and/or orderer nodes.  If you have not done so, I'd advise taking a look at http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/ to better understand the current Fabric architecture.

There is a [project](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-rest) to provide a REST API server in front of Fabric nodes.  It was not updated to support Fabric v1.1 (at least not yet) but does support Fabric v1.0 and should provide at least an example of how to add a REST API in front.

I'd also advice taking a look at the [samples](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples) which are documented [here](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/samples.html) as well.  The fabcar sample provides a nice, simple example of how to connect a Node.js application to Fabric.